# Maximal relative error on Wheatstone Bridge

Tags: wheatstone-bridge

I just need a hint about calculating the part a. How can I deduce the values I need to take into account to calculate the maximal relative error? I guess 'x' needs to be 10, that is, the maximal value in order to obtain the maximal error. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1) Using the resistor value constraints specified in the question, select values for the bridge's resistors R1, R2, R3, and Rx so that (a) the bridge is balanced for the condition x=0 (\$R_{x}=1000\; \Omega\$) AND (b) the bridge exhibits maximum sensitivity for the x=0 case. ([SENSITIVITY HINT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110588/sensitivity-of-wheatstone-bridge))

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3MsGW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Step 2) Let x=10 (\$R_{x}=1100\; \Omega\$). Set the bridge's input voltage \$V_{in}\$ to a non-zero, constant (DC) voltage value \$V_{in}=k\$, and then solve for the bridge's output voltage \$V_{out}\$. (HINT: The solution will be a number times 'k'.)

FWIW, the *system's* sensitivity would be the ratio ΔVout/Δx, with units in terms of "Volts per distance" (e.g., 3 volts/millimeter).