# Backwards proof for balanced Wheatstone bridge

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, resistors, voltage-divider, wheatstone-bridge

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIFAJO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We know that in this Wheatstone bridge if,
 **\$\bf{I_3 = 0}\$**, it can be [derived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge#Derivation) that **\$\bf{\frac{R_1}{R_5}=\frac{R_2}{R_4}}\$** . But could we prove it backwards, mathematicaly, that - if in such a circuit **\$\bf{\frac{R_1}{R_5}=\frac{R_2}{R_4}}\$**, then it will be also true that **\$\bf{I_3 = 0}\$**?

I am asking this question because I've seen in the case of solving such circuit problems this argument being made using the reference of Wheatstone bridge, that as \$\bf{\frac{R_1}{R_5}=\frac{R_2}{R_4}}\$, so the equivalent **\$\bf{I_3}\$** would be **0**.

Comment: simple application of KVL

Comment: How? Any hint, sir? @Tony Stewart. EE since '75

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110588/sensitivity-of-wheatstone-bridge?rq=1   Do you know what is an R Voltage divider?

Comment: Yes, I know what a voltage divider is. But don't we still need to presume that the current(\$I_g\$) branching off the voltage divider is zero in order to use the voltage divider equation \$V_{out} = \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} V_{in}\$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#General_case 
 @Tony Stewart. EE since '75

Comment: When both branches are equal ratio then differential =0V thus 0 current,thus Rx is easily computed from 3 known R's AND matched ratios

Comment: But how do we mathematically derive that when both branches are equal ratio the differential = 0V? @Tony Stewart. EE since '75

Comment: Vin R2/(R1+R2)=VinRx/(Rx+R3) or any Vin (cancels out),  Vout=0 when these match or R2/R1=Rx/R3   you have the wrong ratios

Comment: Sorry I couldn't follow. How do we know that Vin R2/(R1+R2) = Vin Rx/(Rx+R3) ? @Tony Stewart. EE since '75

Comment: You have two simple unloaded resistive dividers. If \$V_G=V_D-V_B=0\$, it means that both nodes D and B are of equal value. The voltage at node D is obtained by using a resistive divider, something you must know (with current division) absolutely: \$V_D=V_{in}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$. Similarly, \$V_B=V_{in}\frac{R_x}{R_3+R_x}\$. Since both nodes are equal, write  \$V_B= V_D\$ and as Monsieur Stewart highlighted, \$V_{in}\$ disappears from both sides and you have \$R_x\$ in a second. If you now consider a resistance between D and B, that's another story and you should better call the EET : )

Comment: You are saying 'if \$V_G = V_D - V_B = 0 \$', but what's the mathematical base for this reasoning; how do we know that its true?  Because if it was true we could simply say that as there is no potential difference so no current will flow (\$I_g = 0\$). @Verbal Kint

Comment: If there is no current in the galvanometer, then there is no voltage across its terminals. The differential measurement leads to 0 V when equilibrium is reached. Having a 0-V differential potential simply implies that both branches divide \$V_{in}\$ by the same amount. Now, if current would flow in the galvanometer, then the expressions of the two resistive dividers no longer hold.

Comment: Sorry that the image in the previous version of my question was misleading, there shouldn't be any galvanometer. I have fixed it now. Please see it. @VerbalKint

Comment: If you want to calculate the voltage across \$R_3\$ you can either use the extra-element theorem (EET) or use superposition: split \$V_{in}\$ in \$V_{in1}\$ feeding \$R_1\$ and  \$V_{in2}\$ feeding \$R_2\$. Then apply superposition by alternatively grounding \$V_{in1}\$ and \$V_{in2}\$ to determine the voltage at the right- and left-sides of \$R_3\$. Do not develop paralleled terms for the symbolic expression. You can then run a quick dc simulation to check if your values are correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prove it the laborious way and ignore the obvious solution just imagine that Vsupply was in fact two identical supplies each independently feeding R2 and R1 respectively.

Then turn those voltage sources into current sources (Norton's and Thevenin's theorums) each respectively in parallel with R2 and R1. Now you end up with: -

- a current source in parallel with R2 and R4
- another current source in parallel with R1 and R5
- Both connected via the component that would have I3 flowing

Now it's a lot easier to solve. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @tiash ok well done on modifying my answer following your edit. I approved the edit btw.